# OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm using `dio` instead of `http`. When I send a login request to the API, I get this error:

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'MY URL' (OS Error: No address
> associated with hostname, errno = 7)

What is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 You do have internet permissions in manifest.
2  Internet Off.
3  Url is wrong.